# How to fix warning could not introspect test class in maven project?

Tags: java, apache, class, loader, introspection

When I start my web application on embedded tomcat from Eclipse I see in log:

```
unknown.jul.logger - Could not introspect classes from MyTestClass...
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyTestDataClass...

at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal
    (WebappClassLoader.java:2889)
  ....
```

How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the root cause is - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyTestDataClass ?

Comment: but when I run mvn test from command line - all ok

Comment: no, this is standard structure of maven project

Comment: sorry I take my words back, cause if it works with maven, you are already good.

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyTestDataClass` is the root of your problem.

It's probably because you refer to classes in `src/test/java` from `src/main/java`. `mvn test` works because they are both on the classpath. In deployment, the test classes are not there.

So fix that dependency (move the class to `src/main/java` or remove the reference, as appropriate) and it should work.